# An uninitialized integer is basically being initialized to 0 (by compiler?)

Tags: c, graph, stack, compiler-optimization

In my Discrete Structures for Computer Science assignment, one function is :

```
int find_impossible_pairs(Graph *g)
{
    int **closure = warshall(g); // Do not modify
    int impossible_pairs;
    printf("THIS IS TESTING %d\n", impossible_pairs);
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (closure[i][j] == 0)
            {
                impossible_pairs++;
            }
        }
    }
    return impossible_pairs;
}
```

As you can see, I forgot to initialise impossible_pairs to 0. But, when I tested my whole code, I will got right answers (not ambigous) which is why I didn't notice this small mistake.

This submission failed when my professor ran this code with his test cases (ambigous value).

I don't understand why it worked fine in my enviornment. I don't know how much information is required to explain the full situation to you guys but I'm using GNU GCC on VSCODE.

As you can see in the code, I inserted some extra print statements to actually determine if it's initialising to 0, and yes it did.

Note that the variable had ambigous values in every other system I tested.

Here's the full code for your reference:

```
// ---------------------------DO NOT MODIFY (Begin)------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct Graph
{
    int n;                // Size of the graph
    int **adj;            // Adjacency matrix
    char **station_names; // Array of station names
} Graph;

/**
 * This function has been pre-filled. It reads the input testcase
 * and creates the Graph structure from it.
 */
Graph *create_graph(char input_file_path[])
{
    FILE *f = fopen(input_file_path, "r");
    Graph *g = (Graph *)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
    // Size of graph
    fscanf(f, "%d", &(g->n));
    // Names of stations
    g->station_names = (char **)malloc(g->n * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        g->station_names[i] = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        fscanf(f, "%s", g->station_names[i]);
    }
    // Adjacency matrix
    g->adj = (int **)malloc(g->n * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        g->adj[i] = calloc(g->n, sizeof(int));
    }
    int edges;
    fscanf(f, "%d", &edges);
    for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++)
    {
        int x, y;
        fscanf(f, "%d%d", &x, &y);
        g->adj[x][y] = 1;
        g->adj[y][x] = 1;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return g;
}
// ---------------------------DO NOT MODIFY (End)------------------------------

/**
 * Q.1
 * Return the number of junctions.
 */
int find_junctions(Graph *g)
{
    int junctions = 0;
    int vertices = g->n;

    // Counting number of stations connected to each station
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; ++i)
    {
        int adjCount = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < vertices; ++j)
        {
            adjCount += (g->adj[i][j]);
            if (adjCount >= 4)
            {
                ++junctions;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return junctions;
}

/**
 * Q.2
 * Return true if the tour specified in the question is possible for this
 * graph, else return false.
 * Parameter SAME_STATION - If it is true, then question 2(a) must be solved.
 * If false, then question 2(b) must be solved.
 */
bool sheldons_tour(Graph *g, bool SAME_STATION)
{
    // Euclerian Cycle or Hamiltonian Cycle since nodes are always connected

    // Initialize in_degree and out_degree arrays
    int in[g->n];
    int out[g->n];

    // Initialize in_degree and out_degree arrays to zero
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; ++i)
    {
        in[i] = 0;
        out[i] = 0;
    }

    // Calculate in_degree and out_degree for each vertex
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < g->n; ++j)
        {
            out[i] += g->adj[i][j];
            in[j] += g->adj[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Check for Euler Path (b)
    if (!SAME_STATION)
    {
        // Check if there are exactly two vertices with odd in_degree and out_degree
        // and all other vertices have even in_degree and out_degree
        int odd_count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < g->n; ++i)
        {
            if ((in[i] % 2 == 1) && (out[i] % 2 == 1))
            {
                ++odd_count;
            }
        }

        // Clean up: free allocated memory

        return odd_count == 2;
    }

    // runs if same station = true
    // Check for Euler Circuit (a)
    // Check if every vertex has even in_degree and out_degree
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; ++i)
    {
        if ((in[i] % 2 == 1) || (out[i] % 2 == 1))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Clean up: free allocated memory

    // Return true if conditions for Euler Circuit are satisfied
    return true;
}

/**
 * Q.3
 * Return closure, an n * n matrix filled with 0s and 1s as required.
 */
int **warshall(Graph *g)
{
    // Do not modify or delete pre-filled code!
    int **closure = (int **)malloc(g->n * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        closure[i] = calloc(g->n, sizeof(int));
    }

    // Code goes here
    // Copying Adjacent Matrix to Empty Closure Matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < g->n; j++)
        {
            if (g->adj[i][j] != 0)
            {
                closure[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                closure[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Applying Warshall's Algorithm
    for (int k = 0; k < g->n; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < g->n; j++)
            {
                if (closure[i][j] || (closure[i][k] && closure[k][j]))
                {
                    closure[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return closure; // Do not modify
}

/**
 * Q.3
 * Return the number of impossible pairs.
 */
int find_impossible_pairs(Graph *g)
{
    int **closure = warshall(g); // Do not modify
    int impossible_pairs;
    printf("THIS IS TESTING %d\n", impossible_pairs);
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (closure[i][j] == 0)
            {
                impossible_pairs++;
            }
        }
    }
    return impossible_pairs;
}

/**
 * Q.4
 * Return the number of vital train tracks.
 */
int find_vital_train_tracks(Graph *g)
{
    int vital = 0;
    int impossible_pairs = find_impossible_pairs(g);
    int temp_adj[g->n][g->n];
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < g->n; j++)
        {
            temp_adj[i][j] = g->adj[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (g->adj[i][j] == 1)
            {
                temp_adj[i][j] = 0;
                int temp_closure[g->n][g->n];
                int temp_impossible_pairs = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < g->n; j++)
                    {
                        if (temp_adj[i][j] != 0)
                        {
                            temp_closure[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            temp_closure[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < g->n; k++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < g->n; j++)
                        {
                            if (temp_closure[i][j] || (temp_closure[i][k] && temp_closure[k][j]))
                            {
                                temp_closure[i][j] = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        if (temp_closure[i][j] == 0)
                        {
                            temp_impossible_pairs++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (temp_impossible_pairs != impossible_pairs)
                {
                    vital++;
                }
                temp_adj[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return vital;
}

/**
 * Q.5
 * Return upgrades, an array of size n.
 * upgrades[i] should be 0 if railway station i gets a restaurant
 * upgrades[i] should be 1 if railway station i gets a maintenance depot
 * If it is not possible to upgrade, then return "-1" in the entire array
 */
int *upgrade_railway_stations(Graph *g)
{
    int *upgrades = calloc(g->n, sizeof(int)); // Initialize upgrades array
    memset(upgrades, -1, g->n * sizeof(int));

    // Stack to keep track of stations to be upgraded
    int *stack = (int *)malloc(g->n * sizeof(int));
    int top = -1;

    // Start with station 0
    upgrades[0] = 0;
    stack[++top] = 0;

    while (top >= 0)
    {
        int current_station = stack[top--];

        // Upgrade connected stations
        for (int i = 0; i < g->n; ++i)
        {
            if (g->adj[current_station][i])
            {
                if (upgrades[i] == -1)
                {
                    upgrades[i] = 1 - upgrades[current_station]; // Toggle upgrade
                    stack[++top] = i;                            // Push the upgraded station onto the stack
                }
                else if (upgrades[i] == upgrades[current_station])
                {
                    // Contradiction found
                    free(stack);
                    memset(upgrades, -1, g->n * sizeof(int));
                    return upgrades;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Free allocated memory
    free(stack);

    return upgrades;
}

/**
 * Q.6
 * Return distance between X and Y
 * city_x is the index of X, city_y is the index of Y
 */
int distance(Graph *g, int city_x, int city_y)
{
     int dist[g->n],visited[g->n];
    for(int i=0;i<g->n;i++){
        dist[i]=INT_MAX;
        visited[i]=0;
    }
    dist[city_x]=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<g->n-1;i++){
        int k=-1;
        for(int j=0;j<g->n;j++){
            if(!visited[j] && (k==-1 || dist[j]<dist[k])){
                k=j;
            }
        }
        visited[k]=1;

        for(int j=0;j<g->n;j++){
            if(!visited[j] && g->adj[k][j] && dist[k]!=INT_MAX && dist[k]+g->adj[k][j]<dist[j]){
                dist[j]=dist[k]+g->adj[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    int final_distance=dist[city_y];
    if(final_distance==INT_MAX){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return final_distance;
    }
}

/**
 * Q.7
 * Return the index of any one possible railway capital in the network
 */
int railway_capital(Graph *g)
{
     int total_distance[g->n];
     for(int i=0;i<g->n;i++){
        total_distance[i]=0;
     }
     for(int i=0;i<g->n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<g->n;j++){
            total_distance[i]=total_distance[i]+distance(g,i,j);
        }
     }
     int min=total_distance[0],current=0;
     for(int i=0;i<g->n;i++){
        if(total_distance[i]<min){
            current=i;
            min=total_distance[i];
        }
     }
     return current;
}

/**
 * Helper function for Q.8
 */
bool maharaja_express_tour(Graph *g, int source, int current_city, int previous_city, int *visited)
{
    visited[current_city] = 1; // Mark the current city as visited

    // Traverse all neighbors of the current city
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; ++i) {
        if (g->adj[current_city][i]) {
            // If the neighbor is not visited, continue DFS
            if (!visited[i]) {
                if (maharaja_express_tour(g, source, i, current_city, visited)) {
                    return true; // Cycle found
                }
            } else if (i != previous_city && i == source) {
                return true; // Cycle found, and it ends at the source city
            }
        }
    }

    return false; // No cycle found
}

/**
 * Q.8
 * Return true if it is possible to have a Maharaja Express tour
 * starting from source city, else return false.
 */
bool maharaja_express(Graph *g, int source)
{
    int *visited = (int *)malloc(g->n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    // Call the helper function to check for a tour starting from the source city
    bool result = maharaja_express_tour(g, source, source, -1, visited);

    // Free allocated memory
    free(visited);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char input_file_path[100] = "testcase_3.txt"; // Can be modified
    Graph *g = create_graph(input_file_path);     // Do not modify

    // Code goes here
    int test;
    printf("%d\n",test);
    // Q.1
    printf("No. of Junctions: %d \n", find_junctions(g));

    // Q.2
    printf("Sheldon's tour (same city): %s\n", sheldons_tour(g, true) ? "POSSIBLE" : "IMPOSSIBLE");
    printf("Sheldon's tour (different city): %s\n", sheldons_tour(g, false) ? "POSSIBLE" : "IMPOSSIBLE");

    // Q.3
    int **closure = warshall(g);
    printf("Transitive Closure =\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < g->n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", closure[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int impossible_pairs = find_impossible_pairs(g);
    printf("Impossible to travel city pairs = %d\n", impossible_pairs);

    // Q.4
    int vital = find_vital_train_tracks(g);
    printf("Number of vital train tracks = %d\n", vital);

    // Q.5
    int *upgrades = upgrade_railway_stations(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", upgrades[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //Q.6

    for(int i=0;i<g->n;++i)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<g->n;++j)
        {
            printf("Distance between %d %d is %d \n ",i,j,distance(g,i,j));
        }
    }

    //Q.7

    printf("Railway Capital: %d \n",railway_capital(g));

    //Q.8

    for(int i=0;i<g->n;++i)
    {
        printf("Maharaja from city %d : %d \n", i,maharaja_express(g,i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a test case:

```
6
Amritsar
Bengaluru
Chennai
Delhi
Faridabad
Gurugram
6
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 0
0 4
4 5
```

Comment: _"why it worked fine in my enviornment"_ - Reading the uninitialized variable makes the program have undefined behavior - so it may behave in any way.

Comment: @ParthJha17 " don't understand why it worked fine in my environment" --> Code's behavior without initialization is not well defined.  Did you expect something well defined to happen?  You were just (un)lucky.

Comment: Uninitialized variables aren't initialized to 0. Probably you run your test under debugger? Can't say why, but under debugger I generally found data initialized to 0. At least under windows...

Comment: `impossible_pairs` is stored in some bit of steak memory that happens to be zero. If you execute the function twice you'll likely find it gives different results. I'd recommend enabling address sanitizer and compiler warnings to try and catch these issues

Comment: Yup, clang or `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` is a good tool.

Comment: @Frankie_C: MSVC debug builds "poison" stack memory with `0xcc` bytes, so uninitialized variables have that recognizable value.  But that's just MSVC; Windows GCC and Clang don't.  Running the same build under a debugger or not shouldn't make a difference, though; under multi-tasking OSes, debuggers are fully non-intrusive.  (Separate process, not running interrupts and their own functions on the same callstack the program being debugged is using.)  Related: [Where do the values of uninitialized variables come from, in practice on real CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71268001)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I understand that. The reason I asked this question was because no matter how many runs I do, even after reboots, it always gives me the same result.

Comment: @ParthJha17 That's one way UB may manifest itself. Tomorrow, it may not give the same result.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I expected it to work in a well-defined manner as every time I tested my code with various test cases, I got the right answers. Just because I got the right answers, I missed that I left that variable uninitialised. All I'm trying to understand is why it's well defined in my environment, so that I can explain it to my professor.

Comment: It's not so much about what the compiler and debugging tools do, but what the C Standard says. It does not guarantee any specific value for an uninitialized variable. Just because it is 0 in your environment does not mean that it is well defined. It isn't, but *happens* to be 0. Re *"I missed that I left that variable uninitialised"* – the compiler should have told you. That's what you missed: the **compiler warning**.

Comment: _"why it's well defined in my environment"_ - It is not. It has UB in your environment too unless the compiler has some sort of extension enabled that actually zero-initializes variables left unintialized.

Comment: I'm curious. Which modern compilers do not warn about using an undefined variable at compile time? Dataflow analysis has come on a long way. I have seen teaching compilers that will code for a hard system trap by default on accessing an uninitialised variable but never one that would let this sort of error pass without a warning. What compiler and version is the OP actually using?

Comment: @MartinBrown MS VC showers you with irrelevant warnings to promote its own agenda, divergent from standard C. Unless they are disabled by placing `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE` before any library headers it can be very hard to pick out significant warnings from the dross.

Comment: @ParthJha17 "I'm trying to understand is why it's well defined in my environment, so that I can explain it to my professor." --> Unfortunately, it is not well defined even if you tested it dozens of times.  So doubtful that an explanation to the professor will go in your favor.  Tip: Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings to to help identify many issues.

Comment: @WeatherVane MSC in debug mode also faults access to "uninitialised" variables at runtime through filling the stack with 0xcc bytes so it seems highly unlikely that this is the explanation even if the OP ignored the compiler warnings.  It appears that the OPs environment either initialises the stack to zero or that by pure luck his variable happened to sit on a location that had been left with the value of zero by previously executed code. I'm with chux here - try to find such problems at compile time if you can.

Comment: @MartinBrown I don't know what point you are trying to make. Several hours ago I wrote: Re *"I missed that I left that variable uninitialised"* – the compiler should have told you. That's what you missed: the **compiler warning**.

Comment: @WeatherVane my point is that he can't have been using MSVC or it would still have generated a runtime warning in the debugger.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is there any way to use `-Wall` on MSVC without having the standard headers spew a flood of warnings like `... warning C4514: 'fpclassify': unreferenced inline function has been removed`?  Those `#define`s didn't reduce the number of those. (https://godbolt.org/z/WhGaoM5PT).  Fortunately I don't regularly use MSVC except to look at its asm output, but I understand some people are stuck using it as their main compiler.  Maybe its intended for use with VS as an IDE that hides or separates warnings from their own standard headers?

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't know. Even a simple `printf("%d\n", 42);` compiled with -Wall issues a warning about `printf` in `stdio.h` not being inlined, so it seems to be picking at its own library headers. I don't use an IDE for C, but compile and link from a command line (sometimes with a makefile if the code is more complicated). There is a list of compiler options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=msvc-170).